# d3 geojson changing from one index to the another

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I have this geojson, collecting the values I need to show (subindex_1, etc) and the geodata.

`{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "OBJECTID": 1454, "STAT_LEVL_": 2, "NUTS_ID": "AT11", "SHAPE_Leng": 6.10844425190757, "SHAPE_Area": 0.471234982131153, "subindex_1": 0.196981355, "categories": 4.0, "subindex_2": 0.414249207, "categori_1": 4.0, "subindex_3": -0.214948039, "categori_2": 3.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 17.064420928067833, 48.118214904109713 ], [ 17.06623558686395, 48.03111128189601 ], [ 17.091640810009615, 47.708102016186864 ], [ 16.746855638747039, 47.680882134245081 ], .... ] ] } },`

Each subindex is connected to a category, and that category decides the color class

```
d3.json("eu.geo.json", function(world) {    
  svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(world.features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "nut cat" + d.properties.categories; })
```

As long as i show only one subindex it works fine, and the resultant image is nice.

Now what I can't figure out is how to get the class of each eu area change based on a new category when I choose for example subindex_2(categori_1). The classes are five and fixed, so AT11 should change from .cat4 to .cat3

```
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change(world));
function change(d){
    if(this.value == 'subindex_2') {
             //  alert("color change here");
             }
```

Any help? As you can see from the question, I'm quite new to d3, probably what I'm asking is obvious but In a day of searching I haven't figured out how to do it.

---

edit:
I'll try to explain better. 
I have a geojson table with an ID and three columns giving the category that says in which category that region should appear:

```
     ID  |  C1  | C2  | C3  |  geodata   
  ----------------------------
    AT11 |   1  |  2  |  3  |  ...
    FR30 |   1  |  3  |  1  |  ...    
    RO52 |   5  |  4  |  3  |  ...

1:red
2:orange
3:yellow
4:green
5:blue
```

I need to have the choropleth change on a click from C1 to C2 or from C3 to C1 or any possible combination. Which one is the best solution? Should I assign to each path the ID? Is there no way to automatically do that with d3.js ?

This is my full code up to now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  background: #fcfcfa;
}

.stroke {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.fill {
  fill: #fff;
}

.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.land {
  fill: #222;
}

.boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(200,200,200,0.75);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(120,120,120,0.55);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #eee;
}

  .tooltip-title{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .sub1 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .sub2 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .sub3 {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .hide{
    font-size:0px;
  }
.cat1{
  fill: #f00;
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: .2px;
}
.cat1.hover{
    fill: rgba(255,150,150,0.50);
}
.cat2{
  fill: #fd0;
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: .2px;
}
.cat2.hover{
    fill: rgba(255,200,150,0.50);
}
.cat3{
  fill: #ff0;
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: .2px;
}
.cat3.hover{
    fill: rgba(255,255,150,0.50);
}
.cat4{
  fill: #df0;
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: .2px;
}
.cat4.hover{
    fill: rgba(200,255,150,0.50);
}
.cat5{
  fill: #0f0;
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: .2px;
}
.cat5.hover{
    fill: rgba(150,255,150,0.50);
}
.hover {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}
form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="sub1" checked> subindex_1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="sub2"> subindex_2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="sub3"> subindex_3</label>
</form>
<script>
var index = 'subindex_1';
var width = 860,
    height = 860;

var projection = d3.geo.sinuMollweide()
    .center([-5, 0])
    .scale(1035)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip-title");
tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "sub1");
tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "sub2");
tooltip.append("div")
    .attr("class", "sub3");


var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("defs").append("path")
    .datum({type: "Sphere"})
    .attr("id", "sphere")
    .attr("d", path);

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "stroke")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "fill")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);


d3.json("eu.geo.json", function(world) {

    svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(world.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "nut cat" + d.properties.categories; })
    .attr("class1", function(d) { return "cat" + d.properties.categori_1; })
    .attr("class2", function(d) { return "cat" + d.properties.categori_2; })
    .on("mouseenter", function(d) {


    d3.select(this).classed('hover', true);
          tooltip.transition()
            .duration(100)
            .style("opacity", 1);
          tooltip.select('.tooltip-title')
            .text(d.properties.NUTS_ID);
          tooltip.select('.sub1')
            .text("subindex_1: " + d.properties.subindex_1); 
          tooltip.select('.sub2')
            .text("subindex_2: " + d.properties.subindex_2);
          tooltip.select('.sub3')   
            .text("subindex_3: " + d.properties.subindex_3 );
        })
        .on("mousemove", function(d) {
          tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX+5) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY+5) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function(d) {
            d3.select(this).classed('hover', false);
            tooltip.transition()
            .duration(100)
            .style("opacity", 0);
        });
    d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change(world));

    function change(d){
        if(this.value == 'sub1') {
            d3.selectAll('.sub1').classed('hide', false);
            d3.selectAll('.sub2').classed('hide', true);
            d3.selectAll('.sub3').classed('hide', true);
        };
        if(this.value == 'sub2') {
            //svg.selectAll("path").classed('cat' + d.properties.categori_1, true);
            d3.selectAll('.sub1').classed('hide', true);
            d3.selectAll('.sub2').classed('hide', false);
            d3.selectAll('.sub3').classed('hide', true);
        };
        if(this.value == 'sub3'){
            svg.selectAll("path").classed('cat' + d.properties.categori_2, true);
            d3.selectAll('.sub1').classed('hide', true);
            d3.selectAll('.sub2').classed('hide', true);
            d3.selectAll('.sub3').classed('hide', false);
        }
    }
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");


</script>
<div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what you want to do. Is it just to change the color of a particular path with _catx_ class? Could you have a default color assigned to the paths with `nut` class in CSS, and then dynamically assign a color to the class selected: e.g. `d3.selectAll("path.cat2").attr("stroke","#00ff00");`

Comment: That would change for all cat2 the color, while I need, for each region to change the color to another category taken again from the geojson file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was much easier than what it seemed, I got stuck somehow in trying to have a different function outside the json one and trying to solve it with normal programming, while in reality with the great way d3 works it's really just one line that I needed, so I just made this changes:

```
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change(world)
{
  if(this.value == 'sub1') {
    d3.selectAll('path.nut').attr('class', function(d) { return "nut cat" + d.properties.categories;});
  };
  if(this.value == 'sub2') {
    d3.selectAll('path.nut').attr('class', function(d) { return "nut cat" + d.properties.categori_1;});
  };
  if(this.value == 'sub3'){
    d3.selectAll('path.nut').attr('class', function(d) { return "nut cat" + d.properties.categori_2;});
   };
}
);
```

Thank you mccannf for your comment, it really got me on the correct road to the solution.